# Needs to develop in textmate using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, textmate, textmatebundles

I started to use textmate in my projects now.
But I'm having problems to run (command+R) javascript and node.js.
Every time I run my file, the xcode try compile it.

What do I need to do to compile my js files in the browser or in other tool to test?
And node.js, what do I need to do?

I read about PATH, NODE_PATH... and other thinks but it didn't help me.

It question is bad (noob), but I'm lost, its my first contact with the tool.

Comment: Which js bundle are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that when you open JavaScript files from the Finder, they open in Xcode/Dashcode instead of TextMate (which I remember being pretty common), or are you saying something else?

Comment: @JakubHampl I installed Javascript Tools [link](http://www.andrewdupont.net/2006/10/01/javascript-tools-textmate-bundle/)... What do you use? Any suggestion?

Comment: No when I open @JohnFlatness, my problem is when i will compile my file, it happens on xcode and it will generate errors.

Comment: And when you say run you mean pressing command-R or clicking on the cogwheel, and going to JavaScript Tools menu and clicking run?

Comment: @JakubHampl When I say run, mean pressing command-R.

Comment: And using the cogwheel works?

Comment: @JakubHampl No, the same problem... I don't know if is a configuration  problem or other thing.

Comment: That's really pretty weird, since if you look into the [source of that command](https://github.com/subtleGradient/javascript-tools.tmbundle/blob/master/Commands/Run%20in%20Node_js.tmCommand) it does nothing in common with Xcode. Are you really sure you are clicking on `Run in Node.js`?

Comment: @JakubHampl Yes, i am clicking on Run in Node.js. I really don't know what I can do now